# Importing ics file in Ubuntu Phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sync, calendar

When I try to import ics calendar into my Ubuntu Touch phone using syncevolution, it fails. Any idea what is wrong here:

```
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~/Downloads$ syncevolution --import Work.ics
backend=evolution-calendar database=system-calendar
#0: 008c1ab5-a44d-47cd-b251-ddef0e87f896-rid

phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~/Downloads$ syncevolution --print-items
[ERROR] error code from SyncEvolution error parsing config file (local,
status 20010): backend not supported by any of the backend modules
(syncxmlrpc, syncsqlite, syncqtcontacts, syncmaemocal, synckcalextended,
syncfile, syncecal, syncebook, syncdav, syncactivesync, provideruoa,
platformgnome) or not correctly configured (backend=select backend
databaseFormat= syncFormat=)
[ERROR] no datastore selected
[ERROR] backend property not set
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when launching the synchronisation between my ubuntuphone and a radicale server. This happened just after the last system update of the phone OTA-13 of the 20160913.